# How can I open Sublime Text 2 files from the command line in linux to a tab, not a new window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sublimetext2

I have ST2 setup so that I can do 'sublime file.txt' and it will open in a ST2 window. But how can I make it open in a new tab in the currently open window?

Comment: In my installation it opens the file in a new tab. How did you install SublimeText2?

Comment: I moved the tarball extraction to /usr/lib/ made symlink to it with: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try Sublime command line help

subl --help
    Sublime Text 2 Build 2217

```
Usage: subl [arguments] [files]         edit the given files
   or: subl [arguments] [directories]   open the given directories
   or: subl [arguments] -               edit stdin

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -s or --stay:        Keep the application activated after closing the file
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

--wait is implied if reading from stdin. Use --stay to not switch back
to the terminal when a file is closed (only relevant if waiting for a file).

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific
location.
```

After you have opened a new window the subsequent files should be added there as per the default behavior.

Comment: According to [this userecho](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/87972-allow-editing-stdin-on-linux/) and my own experience with that same build, specifying `stdin` as a file is only an option with OS X.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand how this question is related of editing stdin?

Comment: Apologies Mikko, earlier I was looking for information about why my build didn't have the stdin option. After finding out I went back through my stack of search result tabs, trying to leave helpful information. Shouldn't have left anything here :)

Comment: Using --new-window --wait worked perfectly for me to use Sublime Text 2 as my default text editor for Mercurial.

Comment: Also here is my EDITOR trick so that Git uses Sublime for commit messages: https://github.com/miohtama/ztanesh/blob/master/zsh-scripts/rc/39-osx-vars and https://github.com/miohtama/ztanesh/blob/master/zsh-scripts/bin/subl-wrapper

Comment: If it's opening in a new window by default, you probably have the wrong dbus address in your local terminal session. This can happen if you're using tmux. export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in your tmux terminal, set it to the value you get in a new local terminal window.

Answer (score 30):

This works on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
subl filename
```

or

`subl -n filename` (if you want it to open in a seperate window)

Answer (score 6):

```
subl fileName
```

and if you want to open a new file use

```
subl -n new_file_name
```

Comment: Tested and comfirmed the top one

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207695).

Answer (score 2):

another option is:
to open file.

```
[sublime index.html script.js styles.css]
```

to open a folder [ sublime folderName ]